# How to trigger the On-Screen-Keyboard in Windows 7 by clicking on an input?

Tags: windows, events, on-screen-keyboard

Well, I'd like to show up the On-Screen-Keyboard when the user clicks onto **any control which needs a text-input**. System-wide.

The reason: I am using a touchscreen for some projects I've been working on and needed to open the On-Screen-Keyboard manually every time me or someone else had to type something.

Are there any possibilities, capturing a system-wide event for that? Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I am currently looking into a solution like this. It's been a feature well implemented on mobile platforms, but nothing on the desktop! Hopefully something will come along as a result of the Touch Centric strategy for Windows 8.

The closest, but most expensive thing I found is M T Soft TS Keyboard http://www.imgpresents.com/mtsts/mtsts.htm?babelfish=translate